# mysql group and sort a UNION

Tags: mysql

In my **guestbook** I have 2 tables: `messages` and `replies`.
Now, I want to get all messages grouped by id (means that message and corresponding replies will be grouped/together) and sorted by date DESC (the newest messages will be first; if a message is the oldest one, but the corresponding reply is the newest of all messages, this group will be on the top of the table), while replies will be sorted by date ASC (oldest reply on the top).
Here my mysql query that works good except it doesnt sort replies by date ASC

```
SELECT msg.id as id, msg.comment, msg.date_added as date_added, 0 as is_reply
  FROM messages AS msg 
UNION 
SELECT reply.msg_id as id, reply.comment, reply.date_added as date_added, 1 as is_reply
  FROM pg_reply as reply 

GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY date_added DESC, is_reply ASC
```

`is_reply ASC` doesnt do the job as I supposed

`reply.msg_id` specifies id of reply's parent (`messages.id`)

What the result should look like>

```
- message A
- oldest reply B 
- old reply C
- new reply Z  // this is the newest message in the guestbook 
- newer message E // is newer than A but older than the newest message in the guestbook, which is Z
- reply F // (this reply is newer than all messages but message Z)
```

Comment: How are replies associated with their parent message?  Namely, how do you know what message a reply is replying to?  I don't see any field that contains this mapping.

Comment: What field do you use to link messages and their replies? Does reply have a origmsg_id field?

Comment: @squawknull @Johan oh, I forgot, reply.msg_id is reply's parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I'm going to assume that reply.msg_id is a linkfield to the original message.

```
SELECT id, comment, date_added, is_reply FROM (
  SELECT 
    msg.id as id
    , msg.comment
    , msg.date_added as date_added
    , 0 as is_reply
    FROM messages AS msg 
UNION 
  SELECT 
    reply.msg_id as id
    , reply.comment
    , reply.date_added as date_added
    , 1 as is_reply
  FROM pg_reply as reply ) AS allmsg
ORDER BY id DESC, is_reply, date_added DESC
```

This works assuming that `msg_id` is an autoincrement field and that newer id's also have a newer `date_added` timestamp.

**Remarks on the original code**
In your original code you have

```
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY date_added DESC, is_reply ASC
```

The `GROUP BY` implicitly orders on `id` ASC; the following `ORDER BY` **overrides** that and orders by `date_added` first and `is_reply` second.
However if `date_added` is a `datetime` then the chance of two post having the same time are remote (esp. for replies, *it takes time to write them*),
so the 2nd order clause hardly ever gets used.

`GROUP BY` should only be used if you have an aggregate function in your `select`, such as `SUM` or `COUNT`

*If you want to remove duplicates from your select **do not use** group by, use distinct as in `select distinct a,b,c from table1 where ...`*

Comment: thank you. Well I didn't know that order by clauses work only for items with equal values, good to know

Comment: Yes, the 2nd order by clause only works when the 1st order by clause starts spitting out identical values.

Answer (score 1):

similar solution:

```
SELECT sort, project, reviewdate, reviewby, subject, venue, filename, remarks1, remarks2, url
FROM (

   SELECT '1' AS sort, project, last_updated AS reviewdate, reviewby, concat( project, '(', 
    TYPE , '): ', subject ) AS subject, venue, filename, remarks1, remarks2, concat( project, '/', 
    TYPE , '/', filename ) AS url
   FROM `upload_cmg` 
   WHERE (
     (
      subject LIKE '%prt%'
      OR project LIKE '%prt%'
      OR TYPE LIKE '%prt%'
     )
     AND (
      subject LIKE '%mouda%'
      OR project LIKE '%mouda%'
      OR TYPE LIKE '%mouda%'
     )
   )
   UNION SELECT '2' AS sort, project, last_updated AS reviewdate, reviewby, concat( project, '(', 
    TYPE , '): ', subject ) AS subject, venue, filename, remarks1, remarks2, concat( project, '/', 
    TYPE , '/', filename ) AS url
   FROM `upload_cmg` 
   WHERE subject LIKE '%mouda%'
   GROUP BY url
) AS vin
ORDER BY sort, reviewdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a message parent field in both and sorting on that as your primary sort, with date then being the sort after that.. otherwise you will have replies showing up mixed up with other messages that were posted between replies.  You can have the message parent of a non-reply message be itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, comment, date_added, is_reply
FROM (
    SELECT msg.id as id, msg.comment, msg.date_added as date_added, 0 as is_reply
      FROM messages AS msg 
    INNER JOIN pg_reply as reply
    ON reply.msg_id = msg.id
    GROUP BY msg.id, msg.comment, msg.date_added, 0 as is_reply
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN MAX(reply.date_added) > msg.date_added THEN MAX(reply.date_added) ELSE msg.date_added END DESC
    UNION 
    SELECT reply.msg_id as id, reply.comment, reply.date_added as date_added, 1 as is_reply
    FROM pg_reply as reply 
    ORDER BY date_added ASC ) a
ORDER BY id
```